# iframe resizing window with overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

As you all know iframe's are archaic but I wish to have a responsive one. Basically the video always needs to be 100% of the available screen height (which is actually 94.2% because of the banner at the top of every webpage of the site) even when changing window size. I was just wondering how to set the width so it is always 16:9 because at the moment the video displays as a strip:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="video-overlay" onclick="hide()">
  <h2>Video</h2>
</div>

<script>
    function hide() {
        document.getElementById("video-overlay").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

#iframe {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    height: 94.2vh;
}

#video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 23.4%;
    width: 53.3%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#video-overlay h2 {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 5%;
}
```

Comment: I had a look at html https://jsbin.com/puqajamoxo/edit?html,output I cannot reproduce the error, could please provide a little more infos?

Comment: Please create a full fiddle. Also, add an image that explain what's wrong so we could understand the problem and not have to guess.

Comment: @GibboK clearly the overlay doesn't work properly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6L3w3s7d/

Comment: ur question is not clear. Whether you want you video 100% height of the page like here - https://jsfiddle.net/pm2ujabv/ ?, 
or you want maintain aspect ratio 16:9 for the actual height and width http://prntscr.com/9oqbsv ?

Comment: Can I not do both? So that video is 100% height and width changes dynamically so the ratio is always 16:9?

Comment: Not sure if you just [want a iframe that permanently resizes to 16:9](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/xfg88tgf/)?

Comment: @fdsfdf no that would just make the width be > 100% because the ratio is 16:9, you can have 100% width and perspective height as for 16:9, but the other way around would cripple your video.